# javascript change class of multiple inputs onclick

Tags: javascript, css, class, onclick

I wanted to change the class of some inputs of my form having a class='mypost_title' at onclick.

I tried this and it doesn't work

```
<a href='' onclick='popup_mypost(e)'>change me</a>
<a href='' id=edit-href onclick='popup_mypost(e)'>back me</a>

<script>
    function popup_mypost(e) 
    {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("mypost_title");
        for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) 
            {
            inputs[i].className = "change";
            }

        var edit_href = document.getElementById("edit-href");
        edit_href.onclick = function()
        {
            var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("change");
            for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) 
                {
                inputs[i].className = "mypost_title";
                }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i think its: getElementsByClassName(..); you missed 's' in Element

Comment: @Sudhir Good suggestion, but I dont think this works well crossbrowser.

Comment: NO. I can't understand jquery.. :( only javascript. but if it's simple, then ok

Comment: you missed s in document.getElementsByClassName(); please use firebug,

Comment: @Sudhir yup, thanks I missed the 's'

Comment: @IvorySantos, glad it worked for you, but, if that doesnt work well crossbrowser, you might want to take a look at some samples for the same:: http://ejohn.org/blog/getelementsbyclassname-speed-comparison/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method is `getElementsByClassName` - ie, you missed an `s`!

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 1):

For a jQuery approach see my code below. Personally I find this easier to read and follow. Also this will work fully cross-browser!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mypost_title").each(function() {
        $(this).addClass("change");
    });
});

</script>
```

I have had a quick check for cross-browser compatibility with `getElementsByClassName` and the results have been quite surprising. IE8 and below do not support this! Please see this table here for the [tests](http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname).

---

**Edit**

I am guessing a little at what you are looking for here. Here is my interpretation:

When one of these div's is clicked you want to add the `change` class to the clicked one and remove the `change` class from all the others?

In which case you would do:

```
//This focus event will fire when the user "focuses" on an input
$(".mypost_title").focus(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("mypost_title");
    $(this).addClass("change");
});

//This blur event will fire when the user clicks outside the input, or tabs out etc
$(".mypost_title").blur(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("change");
    $(this).addClass("mypost_title");
});
```

Comment: how would I know if that function is the one I am calling? I have onclick='popup_mypost(e)' . Since you told me that getElementsByClass is not working at other browser, now I wanted to used what you proposed

Comment: @IvorySantos Please check my updated answer, is this what you are looking for? If not can you please show some more of your JavaScript?

Comment: I updated my question, sorry I really don't know jquery. At first, when click, the class must be ="change". Then when the back is click, class must be ="mypost_title" thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change this line and try:

`var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("mypost_title");`